# Display text with conditions on dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I am updating my previous Question:

User has to enter the amounts in text boxes: amt1, amt2, amt3
If they are selecting the option to pay 'Self' value 'S' and they need an Advance payment 'ad' as Yes 'y' then the text box adv1 should display a sum of amt1 + amt2 + amt 3 + $750.
In any other case the value in adv1 should be a 0.00 and of course the text box totalAmt should have the sum always of the amounts always.

I have tried the javascript to get the values of the options onChange and try to evaluate.
However values are not been passed on.

HTML

```
<table width="800" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
        <th>Estimated Travel Cost</th>
        <th>AED</th>
        <td>
            <input name="total" type="text" id "totalAmt"value="" readonly="true" style="text-align:center"/>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Amount (AED)</th>
      <th>Arranged By</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>Arrival (incl Taxes)</td>
      <td>
        <input name="amt1" id="amt1" type="text" value="0" style="text-align:center"/>
      </td>
      <td>
            <select name = "drop1" id = "str" onChange="updateTextVal()">
            <option value="S">Self</option>
            <option value="C">Company</option>
        </select>
        </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td>Local Travel</td>
       <td>
        <input name="amt2" type="text" value="" style="text-align:center"/>
       </td>
        <td>
             <select name="drop2">
             <option>Self</option>
             <option>Company</option>
             </select>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
       <td>Accomodation</td>
       <td>
        <input name="amt3" type="text" value="" style="text-align:center"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="drop3">
            <option>Self</option>
            <option>Company</option>
            </select>
     </td>
  </tr>
       <td>Estimated Total Cost</td>
       <td>
        <input name="amt6" type="text" value="" style="text-align:center" />
        </td>
        <td>
                <select name="drop6">
                <option>Self</option>
                <option>Company</option>
                </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Advance Required</td>
        <td>
                <select name="advReq" id="ad">
        <option value="n">No</option>
                    <option value="y">Yes</option>     
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input name="adv1" type="text" id="adv1"  value="0" readonly="readonly" style="text-align:center"/>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>

 function updateText() {
  var str = this.value;
  var $vel = parseInt(document.getElementById("amt1"));
  var $el = document.getElementById("adv1");
  var val = document.getElementById('ad').value;
  var $eval = document.getElementById('str').value;

    if(val == 'y'){ 
        if($eval == 's'){        
             $el.value = "750" + $vel;
         } else {
             $el.value = "0";
        }
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Your question isn't really a question, and if it where, it makes no sense? What is it you're trying to do exactly!

Comment: I have a text box 'adv1' and 2 options. If user selects 'Self' and 'Yes' on advance required. It should sum the amount entered in the text box 'amt1' and a default amount of $750. The result should be displayed in the 'adv1'

Comment: I was looking for a javascript to get the values from the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html:

```
<table>
      <tr>
      <td><input name="amt1" id="txtAmt" type="text" value="" align="left"  style="text-align:center" /></td>
      <td><select name = "drop1" id="sc"><option value="S">Self</option><option value="C">Company</option></select></td>
      </tr>          
         <tr>
           <td>Advance Required</td>
           <td><select name="advReq" id="ad">
               <option value="y">Yes</option>
               <option value="n">No</option>
               </select>
           </td>
           <td><input id='re' name="adv1" type="text" readonly="readonly" value="" /></td>
       </tr>

   </table>
```

Javascript

```
   document.getElementById('txtAmt').onkeyup = function(){
    var txtV = parseInt(this.value);
    var re = document.getElementById('re');
    var ad = document.getElementById('ad').value;
    var sc = document.getElementById('sc').value;
    if(ad == 'y'){
        // Yes in Advance Required
        if(sc == 'S'){
            // Self
            re.value = 'Self: ' + (txtV + 750) + '$';
        }
        else{
            re.value = 'Company: ' + (txtV + 750) + '$';
        }
    }
    else{
        // No in Advance Required
        if(sc == 'S'){
            re.value = 'Self: ' + '0.00';
        }
        else{
            re.value = 'Company: ' + '0.00';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/4rLhy/2/)

Comment: I need one more condition to be satisfied like if user wants to pay 'Self' or want to pay by 'Company'.

Comment: I have just update my anwser! Please try it

Comment: I am really sorry but am not a java savvy. Can you help me on displaying the value on the text box

Comment: Yes sure! I have just update it.

Comment: It is working in JSFiddle, but not working in my php!

Comment: Please check it yourself! I made it all for you, now it's just simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function that gathers the amt1, drop1 and advReq values and sets the appropriate value to adv1.
Then call it when the page is loaded OR the key is released in amt1 OR drop1/advReq select value is changed.
Don't forget that the value in amt1 might be left empty or not be an actual number.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a onClick function to each of the select elements as `onclick="calculateAdvance()"` defined as

```
function calculateAdvance()
{
if(document.forms[0].drop1.getSelectedValue == 'S' && document.forms[0].advReq.getSelectedValue == 'y')
{
var sum = eval(document.forms[0].amt1.value) + 750;
document.forsm[0].amt1.value = sum;

}
}
```

and change the **HTML** to

```
<td><select name = "drop1" onchange="calculateAdvance()"><option value="S">Self</option><option value="C">Company</option></select></td>
```

and

```
<select name="advReq" id="ad" onchange="calculateAdvance()">
```

Comment: @Nambi : Thank you for the edit.
Was actually trying to set it in line but was unable to find the tags.
Have now referred the styling tags to be used.

Apologies for the inconvenience.